# How to marshall/unmarshall object type when getting values from DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a DynamoDB table in which I have columns. Two of them will always have the same datatype while one column's datatype will vary. How can I unmarshall/marshall it when using DynamoDB. Below is my DTO.

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Object value;
```

It is not allowing directly to map "value" field and throwing an exception.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

**Declare the field as:-**

```
@CustomObjectFormat(separator = " ")
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

**Sample CustomObjectFormat code:-**

The below implementation uses `toString()` to convert everything to String and persist as String data type in DynamoDB database.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter=CustomObjectFormat.Converter.class)
public @interface CustomObjectFormat {

    String separator() default " ";

    public static class Converter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Object> {

        private final String separator;

        public Converter(final Class<Currency> targetType, final CustomObjectFormat annotation) {
            this.separator = annotation.separator();
        }
        public Converter() {
            this.separator = "|";
        }
        @Override
        public String convert(final Object o) {
            return o.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public Object unconvert(final String o) {
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapper to save:-**

DynamoDBMapper will invoke the custom `convert` and `unconvert` accordingly for save and retrieval.

```
dynamoDBMapper.save(accounts);
```

[DynamoDBTypeConverted JavaDoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html)